# Typescript: Mapping arguments into constructor function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am playing around with the typescript language, and I am trying to make a factory function that will take a type, and then strongly type the arguments needed to construct it.
I have the following types

```
type RoseType = {
  cmd: "rose",
  color: "red" | "white",
  height: number
}

type DandelionType = {
  cmd: "dandelion",
  color: "yellow",
  leaves: number
}


type Rose = {
  color: string,
  height: number
}

type Dandelion = {
  color: string,
  leaves: number
}

type FlowerTypes = RoseType | DandelionType;
type Flowers = Rose | Dandelion;
```

And I am trying to build a function that takes the cmd property of the FlowerTypes, and have the compiler strongly type the function.

```
getFlowerFromFactory<
  T extends FlowerTypes["cmd"],
  A extends Omit<Extract<FlowerTypes, { cmd: T }>, "cmd">
>(cmd: T, args: A): Flowers {
const factories: Record<T, (args: A) => Flowers> = {
  dandelion: (args): Dandelion=> {
    return {color: args.color, leaves: 22};
  },
  rose:  (args): Rose=> {
    return {color: args.color, height: 11};
  }
};
return factories[cmd](args);
```

}

This gives a compiler error:

```
TS2322: Type '{ dandelion: (args: A) => Dandelion; rose: (args: A) => Rose; }' is not 
assignable to type 'Record<T, (args: A) => Flowers>'.   Object literal may only specify known 
properties, and 'dandelion' does not exist in type 'Record<T, (args: A) => Flowers>'
```

The wierd thing is that code completion works in my IDE. It can autocomplete the "rose" and "dandelion" in the factories const, but the error appears afterward.
If I replace the generic T in Record with FlowerTypes["cmd"], then it compiles, but the compiler doesn't know what properties args has in my functions inside the Record. I have also tried not using Record but instead using

```
const factories : { [k in T]: (args: A) => Flowers }
```

This gives seemingly the same error.

If someone could help with a way to make this compile, and let the compiler know what arguments are in the args object, that would be very helpful. Or am I trying to do something that is just not possible?
And if someone has a good answer for how to let the compiler know what type of flower the function will produce, based on the input, that would also by very welcome, and thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

To create a factory function in TypeScript that strongly types its arguments based on the cmd property of FlowerTypes and ensures that the compiler understands the correct argument types for each flower type, you can utilize mapped types. Here's how I would do it:

```
// Define your flower types with their respective shapes
type RoseType = {
    cmd: "rose",
    color: "red" | "white",
    height: number
};

type DandelionType = {
    cmd: "dandelion",
    color: "yellow",
    leaves: number
};

// Define the shapes of the resulting flower objects
type Rose = {
    color: string,
    height: number
};

type Dandelion = {
    color: string,
    leaves: number
};

// Create a union type for flower types and their shapes
type FlowerTypes = RoseType | DandelionType;
type Flowers = Rose | Dandelion;

// Create a mapping of argument types based on the flower types
type FlowerArgsMap = {
    rose: { color: "red" | "white"; height: number };
    dandelion: { color: "yellow"; leaves: number };
};

function getFlowerFromFactory<T extends FlowerTypes["cmd"]>(
    cmd: T,
    args: FlowerArgsMap[T]
): Flowers {
    const factories: Record<T, (args: FlowerArgsMap[T]) => Flowers> = {
    dandelion: (args) => ({
        color: args.color,
        leaves: args.leaves,
    }),
    rose: (args) => ({
        color: args.color,
        height: args.height,
    }),
    };
    return factories[cmd](args);
}

// Example usage:
const rose = getFlowerFromFactory("rose", {
    color: "red",
    height: 10,
});
```

Comment: Isnt that duplicated code though? Flowerargsmap and flowertypes has the same information as far as I can se